# File not opening

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, file-handling, masm32

Hello I'm new to masm and the goal is to open a file but my code is not working

I have this snippet of code:

```
.data
filename db "highscore.txt", 0 
handle dw ?
buffer db 100 dup(?)

.code
...
mov dx, offset filename
mov al, 2
mov ah, 3dh
int 21h

mov handle, ax
jc erroropening

mov dx, offset buffer
mov bx, handle
mov cx, 100
mov ah, 3fh
int 21h

mov counter_files, ax

mov bx, handle
mov ah, 3Eh
int 21h
...
erroropening:
    mov dx, offset newline
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov dx, offset errormsg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov bx, handle
    mov ah, 3Eh
    int 21h
...
```

but somehow the file is in not opening, even though it's in the same folder of my asm file. Please help, I'm a newbie here.

Comment: Have you checked the error code? Is your `DS` set up properly? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: what do you mean DS? I have never tried a debugger.@Jester

Comment: `DS` is the data segment register. You need to set it up to point at your data (you should already know this basic thing before you start doing file i/o...) Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I checked the error code it just showed garbage values @Jester

Comment: 8.3 filenames are limited to at most eight characters.

Answer (score 3):

3 observations about your program:

- As Dirk Wolfgang Glomp said DOS uses 8.3 filenames and thus the name is  limited to 8 characters. Your string **"highscore.txt"** uses 1 character too many for the name part.
- When you jump to *erroropening* you already moved the AX register in the *handle* variable. At this point AX has an errorcode and **not a handle**. Nonetheless you use it to close a file after having displayed a message.
- You would better also check the CF delivered by the DOS ReadFile function. Add another routine *errorreading* and in it closing the file would be a sensible thing to do.